# What is the Perron-Frobenius theorem for non-negative matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, nonnegative-matrices

Let $M\succeq 0$ (i.e. $M_{ij}\geq 0$ for all $i,j$). No further conditions on $M$ such as irreducibility, aperiodicity, or what not. What is the formulation of the theorem in this case?

I believe that still the eigenvectors belonging to the largest eigenvalue are all non-negative. However the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_1$ is no longer 1, but rather I believe $n$. What is the statement here?

**Edit:**

Refined and more constrained question in a [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835180/eigenvectors-to-the-largest-eigenvalue-lambda-1-of-a-geq-0-are-non-zero-onl). It's okay for me if this one is put on hold.

Comment: There can be multiple eigenvalues of maximal length. $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ has both $1$ and $-1$ eigenvalues

Comment: Basically you don't get much that resembles Perron-Frobenius unless you insist on at least irreducibility

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188394/perron-frobenius-theory-for-reducible-matrices

Comment: You seem to allow  $A$ to be zero matrix. You cannot expect any conclusions without some more hypothesis.

Comment: I think that there is a full theory out there. It's not that wild. I think so partly because one can decompose the graph into its  (SCCs) strongly connected components (and be they single vertices as in the case of the zero matrix). The adjacency matrix can be brought into a form that has the SCCs on the diagonal in block form and all entries in the upper triangle are zero and in the lower triangle are non-negative. By upper (lower) I mean all entries above (below) the block diagonal.

Comment: I've added a [new post][1] that clarifies my question. It's okay for me if this one is put on hold. 

[1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835180/eigenvectors-to-the-largest-eigenvalue-lambda-1-of-a-geq-0-are-non-zero-onl

Comment: Different authors state the theorem differently. If only the nonnegativity/positivity of eigenvectors is concerned, it is more natural to begin with a nonnegative matrix $A$. For other aspects (such as the power method or the algebraic/geometric multiplicity of $\rho(A)$), you should at least assume that $A$ is nonnegative and irreducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed in some detail on the Wikipedia page. Each irreducible diagonal block of the $M$ satisfies the Perron-Frobenius theorem separately and the results of the theorem mostly carry over to the corresponding components of the eigenvectors. As you suspect, irreducible nonnegative matrices can have Perron-Frobenius roots with multiplicities  other than one if they belong to different blocks. Within the same block, the magnitude can be the same but the phase can be different, and they are always roots of unity (see [this section](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem_for_irreducible_non-negative_matrices) titled “Perron–Frobenius theorem for irreducible non-negative matrices”).