# Eigenvectors to the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $A\geq 0$ are non-zero only at the end of the longest chains when $\lambda_1=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory, nonnegative-matrices

Let $n>0$ and $A\in M_{n\times n}(\{0,1\})$. Suppose the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}=0$ vanishes. Then there is no closed path in the graph, only chains. I have read [the claim](http://repository.ias.ac.in/12751/1/308.pdf) that only the end points of the longest chains in the graph have strictly positive entries in the "Perron-Frobenius" eigenvector, i.e. the eigenvector that is associated to the largest eigenvalue (in our case $\lambda_1=0$). Is this true? If so, how is it shown? (In this question I'm more specific than in an [older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834632/what-is-the-perron-frobenius-theorem-for-non-negative-matrices). I don't mind when that older post is being put on hold)

**Edit**
I use the convention that there is an arrow from $i$ to $j$ iff $A_{ji}>0$. (I noticed from the feedback that this seems to be an uncommon convention).

Comment: It seems very False. First of all, it's the starting points of chains that have that property, and they are not the only ones. In general all nodes with zero column (that is, has no edge incoming) has a positive component on the eigenvector.

Comment: If you consider the transpose of the matrix, or left eigenvectors, it makes a bit more sense, but it is false nonetheless

Comment: why? If I run an R-script it shows that all the positive entries of the eigenvectors (when $\lambda=0$) are at the end of chains (admittedly not the longest ones as claimed in the reference)

Comment: Thanks. But the sense of the arrow is a matter of convention, right? I guess I used the less common convention. How false is it when "it makes a little more sense"? Is there a way to make it precise where the positive entries sit?

Comment: exactly as you said, the vector has non-zero entries (with your convention) at the nodes without out edges, that are the ones at the end of chains, but all the chains and not only the longest ones

Comment: So how can one show that kind of claim? The interesting thing is that the direction of highest growth of the ode $\dot x=Ax$ is along the direction where $x_i$ vanishes except at the ends of the longest chains ... as I just calculated.

Comment: I'm writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, notice that the eigenvalue $0$ may not be simple, so there's no thing as "the" nonnegative eigenvector for $\lambda =0$.  Nonetheless, for nonnegative matrices, we can prove that ALL nonnegative eigenvectors for $\lambda =0$ must have the value 0 in certain entries and may have any value on other entries.

Suppose now that $i$ is NOT the endpoint of a chain, meaning that there is at least an out edges from $i$. In the associated matrix you have, by definition, $A_{ji}=1$ for at least a node $j$.

Suppose now that $v$ is ANY eigenvector for $\lambda=0$ with $v\ge 0$, meaning that $Av=0$. If you restrict on row $j$, you have
$$
\sum_{k} A_{jk}v_k = 0
$$
but all the elements of $A$ and $v$ are nonnegative, and $A_{ji}=1$, so necessarily $v_i=0$, otherwise 
$$
v_i>0 \implies \sum_{k} A_{jk}v_k \ge v_i > 0.
$$
Consequently, ALL nonnegative eigenvectors for $\lambda=0$ have value 0 on the $i$-th component, that is a generic node that is not an endpoint for a chain.

Suppose now that $\hat i$ is an endpoint of a chain, or equivalently, has no out edges. By definition, $A_{j\hat i}=0$ for every node $j$, so the $\hat i$-th column is 0. This means that the $\hat i$-th component of  any nonnegative eigenvectors for $\lambda=0$ may be any nonnegative value, since 
$$
\sum_{k} A_{jk}v_k = \sum_{k\ne \hat i} A_{jk}v_k\qquad \forall j.
$$
In particular, there exists an eigenvector $v$ such that
$$
v_i = 
\begin{cases}
1 & i \text{ is an endpoint of a chain}\\
0 & i \text{ is not an endpoint of a chain}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks Exodd! This is very helpful. Would one still call the eigenvectors of $\lambda$ "Perron-Frobenius-eigenvectors" (I'm not a word-fascist, but it makes communication with others easier). After all they're still all non-negative and associated to the highly degenerate, yet largest eigenvalue 0.

Comment: As mentioned above I find the following thing quite very interesting:
The end points of any chain (incl. length zero) have positive entries in one of the eigenvectors. However the dynamics $\dot x=Ax$ only grows in the direction of the longest chain (++). This is very unlike the case where $\lambda>0$. There the dynamics $\dot x=Ax$ grows by a rate $\lambda$ into the direction of the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue. (++) To see this, suppose $x_n$ sits at the end of at least one chains of length $n$, then it grows like $x_n\propto t^n$ outgrowing anything of size less than $n$ :)

Comment: @Marlo Actually, it's not really surprising. the solution to $\dot x = Ax$ is $e^{At}x_0 = x(t)$, and if you know something about Jordan form, you will notice that in $e^{At}$ there are entries asymptotically equal to $t^n$ where $n$ is the longest chain length

Comment: yes :) The surprising thing is not that one can check that the entries scale like this. But rather that $\dot x=Ax$ converges to the (lin. comb. of) eigenvectorS of the largest eigenvalue when $\lambda>0$, but converges to (lin.comb. of) a specific subset of eigenvectors of the largest eigenvalue when $\lambda=0$. Of course it's not surprising at the level of the theory, but then again nothing is surprising at the level of the theory if it's understood. And surprising i mean in the sense of: Uhh... it should be very different at $\lambda=0$, but uhhh it's the same, but uhh ... almost the same.